# Missing right parenthesis error using order by on a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-order-by

I have this query:

```
select exp.X,
       exp.Y,
       exp.Z,
       expe.A
from table_exp exp
inner join table_expe expe on exp.B = expe.B
where expe.X =
       (select X
         from table_expe
         where A = expe.A
         order by C desc limit 1)
```

And i have this error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

I receive the error when I try to add "order by C desc limit 1"  , if I don't use the order by, it works, but I need it with the order by. Anyone can helps me? Thanks!

Comment: there is an unnecessary after expe.A

Comment: fix it :), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support `limit`.  You can use:

```
where expe.X = (select e2.X
                from table_expe e2
                where e2.A = expe.A
                order by e2.C desc
                fetch first 1 row only
               )
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aeae1b7d1d433ebff9d398661e2a7a7b) is a db<>fiddle showing that the syntax does work.

Comment: I try this, but it gives me the same error

Comment: @Imrik . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  The syntax does work.